# Set push notification Action Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

```
UNNotificationAction *shopAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"ShopNow"

                                                                        title:@"Shop Now ️" options:UNNotificationActionOptionNone];

UNNotificationAction *dismissAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"Dismiss"

                                                                           title:@"Dismiss" options:UNNotificationActionOptionDestructive];



UNNotificationCategory *shopCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"Shopping"

                                                                              actions:@[shopAction,dismissAction] intentIdentifiers:@[]

                                                                              options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:shopCategory, nil];

[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories];
```

I tried above code but in my push notification doesn't display buttons. give any suggestions or example of iOS 10 push notifications with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `category: 'shopping'` in your JSON, or `notification.category = 'shopping';` in NODE .js

For JSON you may also need to include `"mutable-content": 1`, before category.

What server side are you running?

Also, this is in your app delegate hopefully? I made this whole thing into a func I called `setActions()` and then I called `setActions()` inside `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Where does this code reside in your base?